# Android xml layout is greyed out

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-studio-4.0

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxYn.png)

My xml layout in android studio is greyed. I can't add any view into it. Even if I try to add then I can't change any constraint.

Here is my layout code: https://github.com/Aditya425/parse-project/tree/main

Comment: Try rebuilding the project. The xml is fine.

Comment: There is a yellow triangle on the `ImageView`  click on it and see the warning

Comment: When I rebuild the project I am getting `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0..`. What to do?

Comment: The link to layout code seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

Don't Worry about that!
Just Connect your Device with Internet, Close your Project & Re-open it, it will automatically fix.

If not done, try to Sync Project with Gradle Files after reopening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).